# To generate xml with jaxb on the fly

Tags: xml, jaxb, dynamically-generated

I want to create an xml dynamically where the xsd will be provided. Here In the program itself I am able to generate the jaxb object with the name of the xsd that I have given. I want to compile this class on the fly and have to unmarshall the xml (Here the jaxb object is unknown). Can anybody help me in doing this? Is there any better option to do this. Here the xml generated should have some variables statically filled while some should be dynamically filled.

Comment: I have tried generating dynamic entity with the xml file I was able to modify it and generate xml too. https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/toplink/TLJAX/dynamic_jaxb.htm

Answer (score 2):

This is possible. You can compile and unmarshal in the runtime, but what will you do with the unmarshalled objects *then*? I mean, since the classes are generated in the runtime you won't be able to access the data actually, will you?

Ok, but nevertheless. Here's [some code](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/blob/08825174f499e9cf22ed82f904c6c4f3e21eec5f/misc/dynamic/src/main/java/org/jvnet/hyperjaxb3/ejb/dynamic/DynamicCompiler.java) I wrote for dynamic schema generation and compilation a few years ago. And here's [some testing code](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/blob/08825174f499e9cf22ed82f904c6c4f3e21eec5f/misc/dynamic/src/test/java/org/jvnet/hyperjaxb3/ejb/dynamic/tests/TestDynamicCompiler.java) for that. It worked but I have no idea if it still does.

I think compiling classes in the runtime is the wrong way. Better check the [dynamic approaches from MOXy](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/Dynamic). I think you might be interested in [dynamic bootstraping from an XML Schema](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/Dynamic/JAXBContextFromXMLSchema).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried with dynamic approaches with moxy. Though the classes are generated dynamically we can modify it and generate the desired xml. The class name will be the name of the root element and the same can also be given as the file name(xml and xsd).

Comment: So, did my answer solve your problem? Feel free to accept it then.

Comment: I have tried it yesterday itself and saw this after that.